# Python Tortoise fields typing

Tags: python, tortoise-orm

Does tortoise provide type hinting for its models fields. For instance, if I have a tortoise model, which has `some_field = fields.IntEnumField(MyEnum, default=MyEnum.DEFAULT)`, will tortoise models objects have type hinting for this particular `some_field` field as enum? I am not asking specifically for enum but for other fields as well, like foreign key relations etc